# Use case for string matching in a 2 by n grid

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, string-matching, research

In a 2 by n grid there is a character in each cell. A path can start at any cell and then you can move to right or down. This way each path will denote a string written by characters on cells visited in visiting order. I wanna try finding efficient methods for pattern searching queries (number of paths resulting a string) on this grid. But I really want to know if this do have any use case in real life or not. Can any one show me some use case of doing this?